# How can I use div with sub tables to hide data

Tags: javascript, html

My starting point is the first image, from the users perspective there are three tables, but it is implemented as a single html table:
[image: Original, table columns aligned]

It looks fine, but I want to add a Javascript function that toggles to only show the first table (MusicBrainz where potential releases are found) and hide the other two. My plan was to code it so that there are actually three tables within an outer table, then set an id attribute on each table and write function thats find element with said id and set display:none/table row

So I went ahead with html chnages and now have this:

[image: Modification, table columns not aligned]

the trouble is because they are now three separate html tables the columns widths for each table are not aligned with each other because each consider their own data to work out the best way to use the available screenwidth, and now it looks messy.

So it seems i have two alternatives approaches but dont have a solution to either

1. Keep the tables within tables approach, and somehow align the table columns to each other.
2. Revert to the original design and use a different method to hide a particular row, I was considering using `<divs)` but as I understand it you can't have a `<div>` directly after a table element, i.e this is invalid

   `
          
            
            ...
            ...

   ```
      <div id="2">
        <!-- Table 1-->
        <tr><td>...</td></tr></div>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr></div>
      </div>

      <div id="3">
        <!-- Table 1-->
        <tr><td>...</td></tr></div>
        <tr><td>...</td></tr></div>
      </div>
   </table>
   ```

   `

**Update based on Ulrichs answer**

*Html*

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return togglePotentialMatchesLinks()">
```

```
<!--Soft Linked:Start-->
<tbody class="releasegroupingpotential" >
<tr>
<th class="releasetableheading_action" colspan="18" >MusicBrainz Releases where potential links to Discogs have been found</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="releasetableheading_action" >Actions</th>
<th class="releasetableheading_year" >Year</th>
<th class="releasetableheading_title" >Title</th>
```

*Css*

```
.releasegroupingpotential {
    width:100%;
}
```

*Javascript*

```
function togglePotentialMatchesLinks()
{
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("releasegroupingpotential");
    var e;
    alert("No of Elements found is:"+els.length);
    for(e in els)
    {
        e.style.display = e.style.display=="none"
                ?"table-row-group"
                :"none";
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I click on the button the alert in the Javascript displays:

No of Elements found is:1

So it is being called but the tbody does not disappear :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought would be to have three [`<tbody></tbody>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) in your table and give them ids and target them, as it seems you want to target a group of rows anyway.

Vague example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody >
 <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody id="hideme">
 <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
 <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('hideme').style.display='none'">hide middle</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didnt know about tbody thanks, looking good I changed from using inner table to wrapping a tbody around each set that represented a logical table and no html errors, now to see if this will work with the javascript, I'll report back.

Comment: tried implmentation but having no effect, Ive added my attempt to the question - any ideas.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: I've updated with a in-principle sketch, so I guess it's a general debugging issue. (Or maybe non-Chrome browsers behave differently, lumping all the tbodies into one.)

Comment: thanks very much, but because there are actually multiple instances of each type of table  I have to cope with multiple tbodys which is why Ive done it by classname. I have now create a jsfiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/v52588m3/3/ can you see why it doesnt work ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor: yes, your loop doesn't iterate over the array properly.

Comment: Hm., Im new to Javscript, so for in is for properties, tried a few modifications but no luck so far

Comment: oh its a nodelist, whatever that is

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you may add `width` to `td` or `th` so your colunms will be of equal width. You may do it in html or in css.
E.g.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr><td style="width:5em;">1</td><td>2</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr><td style="width:5em;">a</td><td>b</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want the width of columns in the different tables to be the same as each other but I want them to use the screen width available so I cant hard code a value really.

Comment: @Paul Taylor you may specify width for all but one `td` so in will expand to table width. You may also use percentage (`width:5%;`) if you want.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody >
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody id="hideme">
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
    <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('hideme').style.display='none'">hide middle</a>
  </body>
</html>
```